# What are the other ways of saying "I love it", "I'm keen on something", etc

Tags: word-choice

What are other ways of saying "I love this song a lot!" I'm looking for expressions that mean "love very much" or "be fond of" but in a more idiomatic form. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/keen_1?q=keen+ Here, in the examples box, there is a sentence "They were desperately keen FOR information."

Comment: I don't get it :( Is it a mistake?

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, but the initial question was different.

Comment: I can't get enough of it.

Comment: @Bonrey There's a difference between being *keen **for** something* and being *keen **on** something*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't know about in United Kingdom, but in the United States of America, the word "***keen***" is archaic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are commonly used in American English:

> - I really like this song.
> - This song is one of my favorites.
> - I like this song a lot.
> - I really enjoy listening to this artist's music.

Comment: Better late than never :)